# PHP login registration - Can't access $conn variable in other file within a class

Tags: php, html, class, oop, constructor

I would like to use the $conn variable (that is declared in dbconfig.php inside of its class constructor) to make the mysqli_query method work (that is used in login.php inside of its Login class).

For some reason I keep getting the errors like "Undefined variable: conn".

Any help appreciated, cheers.

```
//login_crud.php
<?php

include_once('../classes/login.php');
$crud = new Login();

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $crud->login($username);
}

?>


//login.php
<?php
include_once('../crud/login_crud.php');
include_once('../classes/dbconfig.php');

class Login
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $db = new dbCon();
    }

    function login($username)
    {
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
        $check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if($check == 1){
            header("Location: ../home.php");
        }
        else{
            echo "Incorrect username or password";
        }
    }

}

?>


//dbconfig.php
<?php   
    define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
    define('DB_USER','root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD','');
    define('DB_NAME','tpw_db');

    class dbCon
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die("Connection to database failed");
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: Just declare your $conn variable as public variable in you dbCon Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would advise you to read over some very fundamental principles of OOP. You have a concrete dependency on the dbCon class which will make testing very difficult and are violating almost all of the SOLID principles among other things.

In reference to your actual question, you can't just reference a variable defined in some other classes constructor (then we would also violate encapsulation). You need to assign that local method connection variable to a class instance variable (preferably private) and then provide some sort of getter method.

The below should do it:

```
class dbCon {

   private $conn;

   public function __construct() {
      $this->conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die("Connection to database failed");
   }

   public function getConn() {
      return $this->conn;
   }

}
```

Then you can call your connection in the Login class like so:

```
class Login {

   private $db;

   public function __construct() {
      $this->db = new dbCon();
   }

   public function login($username) {
      $query = mysqli_query($this->db->getCon(), "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
      $check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
      if($check == 1){
         header("Location: ../home.php");
      } else {
         echo "Incorrect username or password";
      }
   }

}
```

Again, I leave with the caveat that I hope this is solely for learning purposes and won't be used in production as it is.